# set value of html input or textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

It is perfectly working. I want to get the current URL and set it inside textarea or input tag. Actually the value is set into a `p` tag.

```js
function urlf() {
  document.getElementById("root").innerHTML = "The full URL of this page is: < br > " + window.location.href;

}
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript</h2>
<h3>The window.location.href</h3>
<button id="my btn" type="button" onclick="urlf()">
            get
        </button>
<p id="root"> </p>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Then create an `input` and assign what you want to its `value` property.

Answer (score 3):

Create an `input` tag and set its `value`

```js
function urlf() {
  document.getElementById("root").value = "The full URL of this  page is:" + window.location.href;

}
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript</h2>
<h3>The window.location.href</h3>
<button id="my btn" type="button" onclick="urlf()">
        get
    </button>
<input type="text" style="width:100%;" id="root">
```

Comment: @khan Works on the snippet. Are you sure that your `input` has the correct `id`?

Comment: that should have worked, there is nothing that is browser dependent. Check carefully

Answer (score 2):

you set the `innerHTML` of the element with the id `root`. According to your code this is:

```
<p id="root"> </p>
```

so if you want to load the content into an input field you need to change the following:

```js
document.getElementById("root").value = "The full URL of this page is:" + window.location.href;
```

```html
<input id="root" type="text" />
```

greetings

Comment: ....those downvotes after 1 second......i actually added this example snippet....works now

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik if you're asking me, I didn't

Comment: just asking who

Comment: `<br>` was copied. removed it now....i guess this is a very good answer quality....

Comment: @messerbill I usually point out those minor mistake to improve quality :) was not meant as a critique.

Answer (score 2):

You just want the current URL in a input? Like below:

```js
 function urlf() {
     document.getElementById("root").value = "The full URL of this page is:" + window.location.href;        }
```

```html
<div>
      <h2>JavaScript</h2>
     <h3>The window.location.href</h3>
    <button id="my btn" type="button" onclick="urlf()">
        get
    </button>
    <input style="width:500px;" type="text" id="root"/>
</div>
```

Comment: SIR i tried this but it is not working on my  laptop

Comment: @khan as I said in the other comment, check your `id`s. Also, does the developer console in your browser say anything useful? If it's not working you should see an error message that may help us understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input id="root" type="text">

function urlf() {
    document.getElementById("root").value = window.location.href;

}
```

Comment: Please explain how this code solves the OP's problem.